# Observe an observable every 60 second and compare to its previous value in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, core-location, rx-swift

What I want to do is:

- Observe the `location` observable every 60 seconds and compare if the distance has passed a threshold compared to the event which was emitted ~60 seconds ago

What happening is in `$0` I'm always getting the very first emitted event, it's not updating every 60 seconds. $1 has the latest emitted event though.

Here's the code:

```
Observable<Int>.timer(.seconds(0), period: .seconds(60), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .withLatestFrom(location)
            .distinctUntilChanged { $0.distance(from: $1).magnitude < 10.0 }
            .subscribe(onNext: { (location) in
                print(location)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`sample` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html), though I'm not sure how it's different from `withLatestFrom`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Can you share a RxSwift example

Comment: Nope, I don't have an RxSwift workspace set up, and I don't have the time to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is to emit a value when the device is going over a certain speed which is a value that is actually provided in the location object. Just use it.

```
extension CLLocationManager {
    func goingFast(threshold: CLLocationSpeed) -> Observable<CLLocation> {
        return rx.didUpdateLocations
            .compactMap { $0.last }
            .filter { $0.speed > threshold }
    }
}
```

With the above, if you want to know if the device has gone over 10 m/s at any point in the last 60 seconds, you would use `sample` as mentioned by Alexander in the comments:

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
let fast = manager.goingFast(threshold: 0.167)
    .sample(Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(60), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance))
```

That said, as a general case of tracking magnitude increase, you would need to use the `scan` operator.

```
extension CLLocationManager {
    func example(period: RxTimeInterval, threshold: Double, scheduler: SchedulerType) -> Observable<CLLocation> {
        return rx.didUpdateLocations
            .compactMap { $0.last }
            .sample(Observable<Int>.interval(period, scheduler: scheduler))
            .scan((CLLocation?.none, false)) { last, current in
                if (last.0?.distance(from: current).magnitude ?? 0) < threshold {
                    return (current, false)
                }
                else {
                    return (current, true)
                }
            }
            .filter { $0.1 }
            .compactMap { $0.0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if even a single location update gives slightly inaccurate update i.e 0.167 the logic breaks. That's why I was trying to increase the timespan

Comment: What I need to check is that if a device has covered 10m in total in the last 60 seconds

Comment: Answer updated, but even with this idea, if even one (sampled) location update gives an inaccurate result, the logic breaks.